# How to create button to open another apx.net web page in VB.Net 2003

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2003

Previously I managed to create a code that can open a new aspx page with a click of a button in VB.Net 2010.

```
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim a = "UpdateForm.aspx"
    Dim openWin As String = "window.open('" & a & "');"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", openWin, True)

    End Sub
```

Now I want to use the same code on VB.Net 2003 but for some reason I got hit with the error

```
Name 'ClientScript' is not declared.
```

Is this because of the difference between 2003 and 2010? Are they any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add `Page` instance before using `ClientScript`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", openWin, True)
```

Note that [`ClientScript` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.clientscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a property defined inside `Page` class, hence you should include `Page` instance to access it.

**Note:**

For ASP.NET 1.1 (and VB.NET 2003) just use [`Page.RegisterStartupScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) as follows:

```
Dim openWin As String = "<script>window.open('" & a & "');</script>"
Page.RegisterStartupScript("pop", openWin)
```

Also you need to add opening and closing script tags because deprecated `Page.RegisterStartupScript` method doesn't have `addScriptTags` parameter which automatically add script tag if it set as `True`.

Related issues:

[Name 'ClientScript' is not declared](https://forums.asp.net/t/1532379.aspx?Name%20ClientScript%20is%20not%20declared)

[Clientscript.RegisterStartupScript not working](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?412789-clientscript-RegisterStartupScript&p=3840139#post3840139)

Comment: I did that. Now I get another message: `'ClientScript' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Page'`

Comment: I see that you should use now-obsolete `Page.RegisterStartupScript` without `ClientScript` because I think you're using ASP.NET 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's gonna be really jarring switching to 2003 from here on out. But at least I got this to work now.